# java what happens when we flush an IO stream

Tags: java, io

When one uses a buffered stream, say, `FileOutputStream`.

```
BufferedOutputStream bf = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
```

Lets say one writes 32 bytes to the stream, and invokes the `flush()` method after that. According to other StackOverflow answers the 32 bytes are handed/copied to OS memory.

Now, if that is true, isn't that were dependant on the OS then? e.g. if we're running this on windows, it also has it's system cache for managing file data. Isn't that we also need to wait for the OS to flush that data to the file, and that is the point that those 32 bytes are actualy written to disk? Or, I'm wrong about this here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets say one writes 32 bytes to the stream, and invokes the flush() method after that. According to other StackOverflow answers the 32 bytes are handed/copied to OS memory.

The word you're looking for is 'written', by the normal `write()` API or its equivalent.

> Now, if that is true, isn't that were dependant on the OS then? e.g. if we're running this on windows, it also has it's system cache for managing file data. Isn't that we also need to wait for the OS to flush that data to the file, and that is the point that those 32 bytes are actualy written to disk? Or, I'm wrong about this here?

You're wrong. All that happens is the `write()`.

Comment: aha, so on invoking flush, data is writtent to OS memory, and the OS is notifyed to write this data onto disk?

Comment: What part of 'all that happens is the `write()`' don't you understand?

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase the question, what does write mean in Java? Write directly from JVM memory space to disk or? That is, the JVM does the writing to disk?

Comment: I've answered that too. It calls the normal C `write()` API or its equivalent. It doesn't implement disk I/O itself.